# comparing two dynamic list in stacked column highcharts angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm trying to compare two data againt each other as stacked columns using highcharts in angular .. the list are combined of parent state and child state the parent is the whole column while the children are parts of the columns .. the task may be easier than it is however I spent the past week looking for a solution to do it like that wihtout any luck here's my chart option I tried to concat both list in one list but it display them together while i need them to be compared every two columns againt each other by state for exemple state client in march 2022 against state march 2023 ofcourse every columns must be stacked if it has children

this is a snippet of my chart option and the data to display

> ```
>     allData = [
>     ...this.parentStatesSerie1.flatMap((state, parentIndex) => {
>       return state.data.map((child: any, childIndex: any) => ({
>         type: 'column',
>         stack: `${this.selectedPeriod1.name}<br/>${state.parentName}`,
>         data: [
>           {
>             y: child.y,
>             name: child.name,
>             color: adjustColorBrightness(
>               child.color,
>               (childIndex + 1) * 0.1
>             ),
>           },
>         ],
>         showInLegend: parentIndex === 0 && childIndex === 0,
>       }));
>     }),
>     ...this.adjustOpacityForMatchingColors().flatMap(
>       (state, parentIndex) => {
>         return state.data.map((child: any, childIndex: any) => ({
>           type: 'column',
>           stack: `${this.selectedPeriod2.name}<br/>${state.parentName}`,
>           data: [
>             {
>               y: child.y,
>               name: child.name,
>               color: adjustColorBrightness(
>                 child.color,
>                 (childIndex + 1) * 0.1
>               ),
>             },
>           ],
>           showInLegend: this.parentStatesSerie1.length
>             ? false
>             : parentIndex === 0 && childIndex === 0,
>         }));
>       }
>     ),
>   ];
> }
>
> return {
>   chart: {
>     renderTo: 'container',
>     zooming: {
>       type: 'xy',
>     },
>     type: 'column',
>     panning: {
>       enabled: true,
>       type: 'xy',
>     },
>     panKey: 'shift',
>   },
>   series:allData.map((serie,index)=>{
>     return {
>       id:`${serie.stack}-${index}`,
>       name:`${serie.stack}-${index}`,
>       data:serie.data.map((data:any)=>{
>         return {
>           y:data.y,
>           name:data.name,
>           color:data.color,
>           drilldown:data.name
>         }
>       }),
>       stack:serie.stack,
>       type:serie.type,
>       showInLegend:serie.showInLegend,
>
>     }
>   }),
>   tooltip: {
>     formatter: function () {
>       return `<span><b>${this.series.options.stack} - ${this.point.name}</b> : ${this.point.y}</span>`;
>     },
>   },
>   legend: {
>     labelFormatter: function () {
>       return allLegendItems
>         .map(
>           (legendItem: any) =>
>             `<div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
>                 <span style="color:${legendItem.color}; font-size: 24px;">●</span>
>                 <span style="font-size: 15px;">${legendItem.name}</span>
>             </div>`
>         )
>         .join('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
>     },
>     symbolWidth: 0,
>     symbolHeight: 0,
>     margin: 1,
>   },
>   xAxis: {
>     crosshair:true,
>   },
>   yAxis: {
>     labels: {
>       enabled: true,
>     },
>   },
>   plotOptions: {
>     column: {
>       stacking: 'normal',
>       dataLabels: {
>         enabled: true,
>         format: '{point.y}',
>       },
>     },
>     series: {
>       events: {
>         legendItemClick: function () {
>           return false;
>         },
>       },
>     },
>   },
>   title: {text: ''},
> };
> ```

Comment: The description of the problem is not entirely clear. Can you visually show what it should look like? The code is also not completely complete, it would be best if you reproduced it in an online demo. You can base it on this sample demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ru1hoeyf/